# IBM XL C/C++ Compiler: check compiler mode using preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, xlc

I am trying to compile a sample c++ file `test.cpp` using IBM xlC compiler on AIX system. The file should be compiled in both 32-bit and 64-bit modes. I am using following commands to compile them in both modes:

`xlC test.cpp` (default compiler mode is 32-bit)

`xlC -q64 test.cpp`

Under `test.cpp`, I have to `printf("Using 32-bit compiler")` if compiling for 32-bit and `printf("Using 64-bit compiler")` if compiling for 64-bit.

How can I achieve this using preprocessor conditionals? Is there a pre-defined macro either for compiler or for machine architecture that tells the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in XLC, if you are using the `-q64` flag, the macro `__64BIT__` is defined.

Straight from [IBM XL C/C++'s documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Fruopt64b.htm):

> If the compiler is invoked in 64-bit mode, the `__64BIT__` preprocessor macro is defined.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `__64BIT__` is #defined by my compiler.